# Removing GPolylines using google maps

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have a point where a Gpolyline line is drawn from a marker to another point. After I click on it a second time, I want to remove the polyline. How do I remove the line after clicking on the marker a second time?

My pseudo-code is as follows:

```
  google.maps.event.addListener(markersArray[0], 'click', function() {
     'draw line to point'
  } );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Asked and answered on [gis.stackexchange](http://gis.stackexchange.com), specifically [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/2049/removing-polylines-from-google-maps/2066#2066). For those of you unaware of this site, and have any interest in GIS, or mapping, c'mon over!